# How to find the second derivative with the implicit function theorem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

$z(x,y)$ is a function defined implicitly by the equation $$F(x,y,z)=5x+2y+5z+5\cos(5z)+2=0$$

I'm trying to find $\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x \partial y}$ at the point $(\frac{\pi}{5},\frac{3}{2},\frac{\pi}{5})$.

As far as I can tell I need to use the implicit function theorem, and I'm able to find both $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$, but the second derivative becomes 0, which is incorrect.

How can I find $\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x \partial y}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\frac{\partial^2F}{\partial x \partial y}
=5\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x \partial y}+5\frac{\partial}{\partial x }\left(-5\sin(5z)\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)
=5\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x \partial y}-125\cos(5z)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}-25\sin(5z)\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x \partial y}=0.$$
Letting $(x,y,z)=(\frac{\pi}{5},\frac{3}{2},\frac{\pi}{5})$, we find
$$5\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x \partial y}+125\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=0.$$
Hence knowing $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ at $(\frac{\pi}{5},\frac{3}{2})$,  you should be able to find $\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x \partial y}$.